# Evaluating expressions using Visual Studio 2005 SDK rather than automation's Debugger::GetExpression

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2005, vsx

I'm looking into writing an addin (or package, if necessary) for Visual Studio 2005 that needs watch window type functionality -- evaluation of expressions and examination of the types. The automation facilities provide
`Debugger::GetExpression`, which is useful enough, but the information
provided is a bit crude.

From looking through the docs, it sounds like an
`IDebugExpressionContext2` would be more useful. With one of these it
looks as if I can get more information from an expression -- detailed
information about the type and any members and so on and so forth, without having everything come through as strings.

I can't find any way of actually getting a `IDebugExpressionContext2`,
though! `IDebugProgramProvider2` sort of looks relevant, in that I
could start with `IDebugProgramProvider2::GetProviderProcessData` and
then slowly drill down until reaching something that can supply my
expression context -- but I'll need to supply a port to this, and it's
not clear how to retrieve the port corresponding to the current debug
session. (Even if I tried every port, it's not obvious how to tell
which port is the right one...)

I'm becoming suspicious that this simply isn't a supported use case, but with any luck I've simply missed something crashingly obvious.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `IDebugExpressionContext` you'll ultamitely end up getting ahold of an instance of `IDebugProperty`.  This interface is implemented by the Expression Evaluator service.  This is, typically, a language specific service.  It's designed to abstract out the language specific details of evaluating an expression.  It understands much higher level commands like "Evaluate", and inspection.

I don't think you're going to get what you're looking for though because you can't get ahold of any kind of type object this way.  Nearly all of the inspection methods return their results in `String` form.  For example you won't get the type `Int32` but instead the string "int".  This makes type inspection next to impossible.

I don't believe what you're trying is a supported case.  The type system being evaluated doesn't exist in the current process.  It exists in the debuggee process and is fairly difficult to get access to.

Answer (score 0):

There's a hack you could do to get more information about the type of a variable you've evaluated using Debugger::GetExpression method.

You could evaluate "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()" to get all the assemblies loaded into the debugee, and cache them in your add-in. You may also need to listen for new assemblies being loaded onto the AppDomain.

Then, run the following:

```
Expression myExpression = Debugger.GetExpression(...);
Expression typeRefExpression = Debugger.GetExpression("typeof(" + myExpression.Type + ").FullName"
```

once you have the TypeFullName, you can search inside your assemblies cache for a matching System.Type, and once you have that, you can dig into it all you want using the standart Reflection API.

Note that this will only work in C#, because of its "typeof" keyword. You'll have to use a different keyword for VB.Net, for example.

Comment: Thanks. I realise now that I didn't mention it in the question, but this is for debugging native code. (If the same techniques work for managed code, that's fine, it would be good to support that as well.)